# Generic detail view needs object pk or a slug

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

But I already refer to primary keys, don't I?

It says this error relates to:

```
class CommentUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['body']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        film = Film.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['film_id'])
        comment = Film.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['comment_id'])
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.film = film
        form.instance.comment = comment
        return super(CommentUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

I am not sure once this issue is fixed if that code above will work but the view I have to create a comment does:

```
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['body']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        film = Film.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['film_id'])
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.film = film
        return super(CommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

My urls.py:

```
path('<int:film_id>/comment/', views.CommentCreate.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
path('<int:film_id>/comment/<int:comment_id>/', views.CommentUpdate.as_view(), name='update_comment'),
```

model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
# user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('films:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.film.pk})
```

And html link I have:

```
<a href="{% url 'films:add_comment' film_id=film.id %}">Leave a comment</a>
<a href="{% url 'films:update_comment' film_id=film.id comment_id=comment.id %}">Update</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpdateView calling [`get_object`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L20) method which required `pk` or `slug` url argument to get updating object. You can change name of argument with `pk_url_kwarg`:

```
class CommentUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['body']
    pk_url_kwarg = 'comment_id'
```